# how to block css from external access

Tags: css, .htaccess, block

Someone had try to steal my css file to use at his site. Can i somehow block CSS file from external access, but not damage my site? Somehow through htaccess or something. Thanks for your advice, any help appreciated.

Comment: It was me. You can't stop me. I'll find your CSS wherever you try to hide it!

Comment: Are you trying to stop someone "hotlinking" your CSS and loading it in their site from your own domain, or from viewing your CSS to copy? Can you also confirm if your web server is Apache (assuming this from the reference to .htaccess) or IIS?

Comment: @pwdst my server is Apache, mm to be clearly he download my css and save to his hosting into folder with my domain name =/ i know that i can do nothing with it but, for future troubles this kind i want to hide css from downloading it, okay i understood that this wasn't a good idea.

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.

Comment: What's there to "steal" in a CSS file? The cure for AIDS in a comment block?

Answer (score 5):

Generate your css with PHP like `style.css.php` and in the code accept a token which refreshes every second. Your main page will include it using the current token `src="style.css.php?token=abc123"`. If the token is valid, it serves it up. If the token is expired, it doesn't.

Dumbest solution ever. Endless workarounds, but might help against that guy who wants to steal your CSS. Worth a try and a good laugh.

**Step 1**: Create a table `css_security_force` in your database with one column `token`

**Step 2**: Create a cron that runs **every second** to update the token (now THAT's secure):

```
UPDATE css_security_force SET token = md5( NOW() );
```

**Step 3**: In your PHP head grab the token from the `css_security_force` table and set it as a variable `$token` then reference that token in the CSS link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css.php?token=<?=$token?>" />
```

**Step 4**: In your `style.css.php` file, grab the token from the database and check it against the query param.

```
if ($_GET['token'] == $token) {
    echo <<<CSS
        body {
            background-color : yellow;
            color : pink;
        }
CSS;
} else {
    echo 'Stop stealing my CSS!!!!!!';
}
```

Sit back and watch your foe's plans crumble before him.

**EDIT**
I got curious and made a <strike>[working demo](http://www.aliencreations.com/stackoverflow/css-security-force/)</strike> (*Took it down after a couple days of 1 second db updates for sanity purposes, but you can easily recreate with the source posted below*).

Here is the source on [Github](https://github.com/SeanCannon/cssSecurityForce)

Comment: Can you implement this somewhere? I would love to see this in action.

Comment: Just a note, but there will be a significant trade off doing this as it's a lot cheaper for your server to serve a static CSS file than to process a PHP page to generate a CSS file.   Also, don't plan to ever cache this on a CDN an have this security hack work.

Comment: Added the Github source. Special thanks to the anonymous downvoter.

Comment: This is nice as an experiment, but horrible if you would use it on a real site. A true performance nightmare! And the CSS would still be visible. If the browser can't load it, the CSS can't be applied... It would only prevent hotlinking. Still a nice experiment though.

Comment: Hence the comment in the php source on git : `None of this code is intended to be serious or used in prod, even though it works.` lol

Comment: Anyway, in the end, the CSS is end up served, and anyone can steal it easily. The only thing that might be possible to protect is background picture, but the general look-and-feel stays the same throughout, which means the CSS is static on those parts.

Answer (score 4):

No.  This makes no sense.  Your CSS file must be available to anyone who can view your site if you want your pages styled.

Who cares if someone uses your style?

Comment: I think he meant that someone was hotlinking his CSS file(s).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Whatever the method, you can't prevent people from loading a CSS file.

Comment: hmm, can i block an ability to open css in new tab?

Comment: @flinth: Once the CSS is loaded into my browser, I can look at it and do what I want with it.

Comment: @flinth your CSS file is either available or not.

Comment: Well, unless it's coming from a fixed IP address, there's no way to block it without making it unavailable to the browser.

Comment: there has to be a way to do it! I know there is a code that works on images that prevent hotlinking.

Comment: @flinth Take it as a compliment someone like your design :)

Comment: @Ray, i care)) he steal my design and sheets sooo, it's annoying

Comment: @flinth  The only option you might have is if you somehow trademarked your look and feel then sue the copier. Apple seems to be very successful in doing this.

Comment: @flinth Welcome to the internet.

Comment: With reference to image hotlinking, it *is* possible to prevent another site othersite.com including an image in their pages by referencing it from your site like <img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/hotlinkedimage.jpg" alt="I've hotlinked this image" />, but it *isn't* possible to prevent that same user saving the image and uploading it to their own site - in the same way it isn't possible to prevent a user viewing your CSS and saving it to use on their own site. Moreover I don't think you should be doing this, allowing people to see CSS is a great way for new developers to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put you cannot block it because the browsers have to have access to them. It is just one of those things you should not worry about. If it were possible, many sites like Facebook and Twitter would be blocking it.